# How do you do multiple SQL statements in one mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say I wanted to do `UPDATE table SET name = 'bob'` and `UPDATE table SET age = 55 WHERE name = 'jim'` how do I do them in the same mysql_query()?

**EDIT:** Since this question has a fair amount of views I'd like to point out that as of PHP 5.5 `mysql_query` and other `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: mysql_query() (and PHP's mysql driver in general) do not support multiple queries in a single query() call for security reasons: It eliminates one of the SQL injection attack vectors. In other words: YOU CAN'T DO IT.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've never tried this, but I think you can use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).  One of the good things about `mysql_query` rejecting multiple statements is that it immediately rules out some of the more common SQL injection attacks, such as adding `'; DELETE FROM ... #` to a statement.  You might therefore want to be careful with multiple statements.

Answer (score 8):

As it says on the top of the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Comment: You can get derision pretty much anywhere else on the internet - Cheers to Leandro for *not* bringing it to SO. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can do "conditional" update in this way:

```
create table test (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(50),
age tinyint
) engine = myisam;

insert into test (name) values ('jim'),('john'),('paul'),('mike');


update test
set age =
case 
when name = 'jim' then 10
when name = 'paul' then 20
else 30
end
```

Hope that it helps you.