# Running two MySQL queries at a time in PHP mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` function of MySQL to get the ID of last inserted row.
When I try to run this:-

```
  mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `posts`
           (`user`, `body`, `time`, `pageID`)
           VALUES('pachykutty', 'testMessage', '2012-10-26 04:59:43', 1);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
```

Gives me error, but When I run the two queries separately like this:-

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `posts`
       (`user`, `body`, `time`, `pageID`)
       VALUES('pachykutty', 'testMessage', '2012-10-26 04:59:43', 1)");
mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

It is OK. I fear that If two clients ran the query same time, their LAST_INSERT_ID will conflict. So I want to run the two queries together without delay. Is there any way?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID is maintained per connection.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821184/how-do-you-do-multiple-sql-statments-in-one-mysql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query like that

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `posts`
       (`user`, `body`, `time`, `pageID`)
       VALUES('pachykutty', 'testMessage', '2012-10-26 04:59:43', 1)");
$var =  mysql_insert_id();
```

mysql_insert_id acts on the last performed query.

So no worries and use above code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. But one doubt. I have on actions.php

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. But one doubt. I have on actions.php  in which scripts.php is included. Scripts.php contains function like insertPost($user,$body,$page); which will automatically do validation of data. All posted data is sent to actions.php and insertPost function is called. If i call mysql_insert_id() in actions.php - neither in insertPost() function nor inside scripts.php - Can I still get the correct value,no conflicts with other users?