# Realize DROP TABLE with SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, security

I have created this code for testing of SQL injection.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("test");
$id = $_POST['data'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberId ='" . $id . "'";
$q = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) 
{
      printf("<h4>Wrong user ID!</h4>");
}
else
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  {
  printf("<h4>Your ID is %s</h4>", $row["memberId"]);
  }
}
?>
```

When variable `$id` is `1' OR '1'='1`, I can see all IDs in the table members.
I would like also realize DROP TABLE, but I can't figure out what to insert in variable id `$id`. I have tried to insert `123'; DROP TABLE sql injection--` in `$id`.

Do you have any idea what to insert in `$id` or how to modify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console it would be: `'; drop table members; select '`

However you are using `mysql_query` and it supports only a single statement.

Here is what the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says:

> **mysql_query()** sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821184/how-do-you-do-multiple-sql-statments-in-one-mysql-query).
As suggested there you can try using [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in your example.

Comment: When i insert this value in $id, drop table is not working. This is just for demonstration on localhost (i use WAMP server, MySQL 5.6.17).

Comment: humm...  let me try something else.

Comment: `mysql_query` must be filtering out the multiple statements, which is a good thing :)

Comment: Thanks, i will try multi_query.